# Learning Galois theory - required subtopics that are prerequisite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, self-learning

This is not a reference request, that is, I have access to many textbooks I am happy with. What I don't know is, what are the things I need to know to get started?

My idea on the path of knowledge acquisition:

1. Group theory
2. Ring theory
3. Quadratic number fields
4. Fields
5. Galois Theory

Is that how I should approach this? Have I missed anything? Should I study linear algebra rigorously first or is it irrelevant here?

Comment: How integral is ring theory?

Comment: From Ring Theory you mainly need the basic notions (ideals, prime/irreducible elements, divisors of zero, integer domains, etc.), and immediately after that the basic of polynomial rings.

Comment: If you study infinite galois theory you need something about Topology too.  On the other hand, often Linear Algebra is very usefull.

Comment: Infinite Galois theory is usually advanced undergraduate/graduate level, hardly what is being asked here. And I'd say Linear Algebra is a *must* for Galois Theory.

Comment: The classic is [*Galois Theory*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndml/1175197041#toc) by Emil Artin starts with linear algebra.

Comment: I'd say cut off ring theory and quadratic number fields. (Quadratic number fields might be nice to look at after Galois theory.) I would add vector spaces, at least the definition and notion of subspace, basis, linear independence, and dimension. For group theory, I would read the basic definitions, but beyond that, I would wait to explore other topics until referred to in your Galois theory reference. Regardless, fields and vector spaces are a definite must.

Answer (score 2):

Galois theory, as presented nowadays in undergraduate classes, is mostly linear algebra with group theory. A finite field extension $\mathbf{K}$ over $\mathbf{F}$, is a vector space over $\mathbf{F}$ and an automorphism of $\mathbf{K}$ over $\mathbf{F}$ is also a linear transformation from $\mathbf{K}$ to $\mathbf{K}$ as $\mathbf{F}$ vector space. So, I think linear algebra is kind of important here!
For the ring theory part, you need to be more precise: after reviewing basic stuff in Ring theory, it's good to view some other things, not really neccessary for Galois theory, but might help to understand concepts better : Einsenstein Criterion, some quadratic rings over $\mathbf{Z}$, ($\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt5] \cdots$ )

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Do you have any opinion on linear groups then? Will these prove important as well?

Comment: Do you mean general linear groups?

Comment: $SU_2$, $SO_3$, one-parameter groups, the lie algebra, normal subgroups of $SL_2$ I meant

Comment: I did not encounter those! As long as the extension is finite, only  finite groups are concerned!